# How to connect to a remote thrift server via thrift client

Tags: thrift

I have created a server and a client in thrift. Then I started the thrift server on my computer. I ran the client on another computer in LAN using my machines IP address.

```
public class ArithmeticClient {

private void invoke() {
    TTransport transport;
    try {
        transport = new TSocket("192.168.0.232"/*this is my machine,which the sever runs' IP address*/, 7911);

        TProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);

        ArithmeticService.Client client = new ArithmeticService.Client(protocol);
        transport.open();

        long addResult = client.add(100, 200);
        System.out.println("Add result: " + addResult);
        long multiplyResult = client.multiply(20, 40);
        System.out.println("Multiply result: " + multiplyResult);

        transport.close();
    } catch (TTransportException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArithmeticClient c = new ArithmeticClient();
    c.invoke();
}
```

}

And I got an Error

```
    org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:185)
    at ArithmeticClient.invoke(ArithmeticClient.java:18)
    at ArithmeticClient.main(ArithmeticClient.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:180)
    ... 7 more
```

How can I solve this thing.

Both computer runs Fedora. versions are different (17 and 19)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **public class NoRouteToHostException extends SocketException**
>
> Signals that an error occurred while attempting to connect a socket to
>   a remote address and port. Typically, the remote host cannot be
>   reached because of an intervening firewall, or if an intermediate
>   router is down.

That's what [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/NoRouteToHostException.html) say, and what I would guess. Could that be the reason? What happens if you try to ping or telnet that machine?

Comment: Firewall was the problem. After disabling it, I can now connect to a remote server.